# magento store view

Tags: magento

I have one main website with one store and 2 store views.

I have added the products to the store and hopefully it will be visible in 2 views.

But here only English pages have the products displayed and no products are displayed on German pages.

I would like to have the products and English pages to be on the German pages too with translation in the name and description.

Please let me know whether it is possible in Magento.

Looking forward for your replies as soon as possible as I am stuck upon my project.

Answer (score 0):

This is out-the-box.

From the sounds of it you may want to consider putting together a test build of Magento and installing the demo products. The instructions for this are on the Magento site. The demo products will provide you with a reference on how multi view works.